# How to fix the TypeError in Python that only shows up for a set of 7 inputs or more?

Tags: python, list, algorithm, error-handling, tuples

I am trying to implement the O(nlogn) divide and conquer algorithm to find the closest pair of points in a set. And it works correctly when the number of points is below 7, however for more than 7 points. It outputs the following error:

File "/Users/Prog1.py", line 82, in recursion
min_distance = min(min_left[1], min_right[1])
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'Point'

For min_distance I want to compare the min_dist of the two sides, which it does correctly for anything below 7 points. How would one fix this?

```
class Point():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"({self.x}, {self.y})"

"""
Returns the Euclidean distance between two points
"""
def distance(point1, point2):
    return math.sqrt((point1.x - point2.x)**2 + (point1.y - point2.y)**2)

def sort_points (Points):
    points_sorted = sorted(Points, key = lambda Point: [Point.x, Point.y])
    return points_sorted

def brute_force (Points, n):
    min_dist = sys.float_info.max

    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i+1, n):
            if distance(Points[i], Points[j]) < min_dist:
                min_dist = distance(Points[i], Points[j])
                closest_pair = (Points[i], Points[j])
    return closest_pair, min_dist

def recursion (Points, n):
    points_sorted = sort_points(Points)

    # Base Case
    if n <= 3:
        return brute_force(points_sorted, n)

    # Find mid-point
    mid = n//2
    mid_point = points_sorted[mid]

    # Split the points into two branches
    left = points_sorted[:mid]
    right = points_sorted[mid:]

    # Recursively find the smallest distance on the left and right
    min_left = recursion(left, mid)
    min_right = recursion(right, mid)

    # Find the closest pair of the two sides
    min_distance = min(min_left[1], min_right[1])
    if min_left[1] <= min_right[1]:
        min_pair = min_left
    else:
        min_pair = min_right

    # Build the strip array to find points smaller than delta
    delta = min_distance
    strip = []

    for i in range(n):
        if abs(points_sorted[i].x - mid_point.x) < min_distance:
            strip.append(points_sorted[i])

    # Return closest pair or even closer if found in the strip
    return strip_closest(strip, min_pair, min_distance)

def strip_closest(strip, min_pair, min_distance):
    strip_min_dist = min_distance
    strip_min_pair = min_pair

# This loop will run at most 6 times
    for i in range(len(strip)-1):
        for j in range(i+1, min(i+7, len(strip))):
            dist = distance(strip[i], strip[j])

            if dist < strip_min_dist:
                strip_min_dist = dist
                strip_min_pair = (strip[i], strip[j])

    return strip_min_dist, strip_min_pair

# Driver code
Points = [Point(15, -37), Point(-45, -36), Point(19, -18), Point(-76, 64), Point(0, -30),Point (-47, -33), Point (7, 8), Point (0, 8)]

n = len(Points)
print(Points)
print(recursion(Points, n))
```

Answer (score 0):

The types used in the different branches of your code are inconsistent.  As far as I can tell, `recursion` is supposed to return values of these types:

```
ClosestPoints = tuple[tuple[Point, Point], float]  # two points and their distance
```

which is what `brute_force` does (I added type annotations and this function typechecks fine with `mypy`):

```
def brute_force(Points: list[Point], n: int) -> ClosestPoints:
    min_dist = sys.float_info.max

    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i+1, n):
            if distance(Points[i], Points[j]) < min_dist:
                min_dist = distance(Points[i], Points[j])
                closest_pair = (Points[i], Points[j])
    return closest_pair, min_dist
```

but once we get to your `recursion` function, if we add a corresponding annotation to it:

```
def recursion(Points: list[Point], n: int) -> ClosestPoints:
    points_sorted = sort_points(Points)

    # Base Case
    if n <= 3:
        return brute_force(points_sorted, n)

    ...
```

then running `mypy` points out a couple of places where you aren't working with the types of values that the code expects:

```
test.py:69: error: Argument 2 to "strip_closest" has incompatible type "Tuple[Tuple[Point, Point], float]"; expected "Tuple[Point, Point]"
test.py:88: error: Incompatible return value type (got "Tuple[float, Tuple[Point, Point]]", expected "Tuple[Tuple[Point, Point], float]")
```

When your code hits these branches, `recursion` returns the wrong type of value, and in turn when its caller (another `recursion` call) tries to destructure that value, it ends up with a `Point` and `tuple` where it was expecting a `float` and a `float`.

My advice is to add type annotations to your code, `mypy` it, and use the errors to iron out these bugs.  (You can debug it without types, but types make this exact type of problem MUCH easier to track down and fix!)